# Elasticsearch search_phase_execution_exception in Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I fetch all my Elasticsearch documents via using scroll api with below code in Python.

```
size = 100
data = es.search(
            index=index,
            scroll='25m',
            size=size,
            body=body
        )
max_val = data['hits']['total']['value']

sid = data['_scroll_id']
scroll_size = len(data['hits']['hits'])
while scroll_size > 0:
    .........
    data = es.scroll(scroll_id=sid, scroll='25m')
    sid = data['_scroll_id']
    scroll_size = len(data['hits']['hits'])
```

In some index I have less then 100 documents and some of them I have more than 30000 documents thats why I use scroll api.

I've written this code via this [tutorial](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-use-python-to-make-scroll-queries-to-get-all-documents-in-an-elasticsearch-index-752)

The code works, but after some time, I get the below error.

```
NotFoundError(404, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'No search context found for id
```

I tried to solve this error with changing scroll. The scroll was 5m and then I set 25m but still get same error. How can i solve this?

Thanks for answering

Comment: Can you define "after some time"? Also I think 25m scroll is not necessary, i.e. there's no way it takes more than 25 minutes to get 100 documents. Remember that each scroll request increases the life span of the scroll context, so `scroll` only needs to be long enough for one iteration, i.e. to fetch "size" documents. In your case, something else must be happening.

Comment: This script runs more than once. In one time It happens this error but the other times i don't get the error. I do not get an error in the same place as the previous runtime.  The meaning of after some time is this. I do get error when indices have more than 10000 doc (like 55000 doc)